# Unable to reference latest angular-ui-router package

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, commonjs

I'm trying to upgrade an Angular1.4.0 app to use the latest angular-ui-router, but I can't figure out how to reference this package in code. I'm using webpack 1.12.9 and node 6.10.2. I've installed package "@uirouter/angularjs" version 1.0.3.

Using CommonJs modules, the following used to work with version 0.2.14:

```
require('angular-ui-router')
```

I've tried variants of the following, but with no luck:

```
require('@uirouter/angularjs/lib')
```

I am getting the error:

```
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module {"core":`{"services":{},"Category": ..... (remaining stack omitted)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

May be this is necroposting but:

I am facing with same issue right now so here is the answer:

Try to use uiRouter.default package when register dependencies.
Like here:

```
import * as uiRouter from 'angular-ui-router';
const dependencies = [uiRouter.default];
const app = angular.module('app', dependencies);
```